# How to find same characters in 2 string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.6

I have 2 strings

```
c = "The quick brown brown fox did jump a"
c1 = "The brown did fox"
```

I am trying to use string c to search c1 and find similar letters. If similar letters are found it should be deleted and added into a new string. When deleting it should delete all the letters up to and including that character.

When you do this process you should get the new string consisting of "Theiox"

Comment: SO is not a code-writing nor a HW-solving service. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
c = "The quick brown brown fox did jump a".replace(" ", "")
c1 = "The brown did fox".replace(" ", "")

new_str = ""
for letter in c:
    index = c1.find(letter)
    if index != -1:
        new_str = new_str + letter
        c1 = c1[index+1:]

print(new_str)
```

First remove the whitespaces since you don't want it in the new string.

Then search in string c1 for the occurrences of the c letters, if found, add them to the new_string and change c1 in `c1 = c1[index+1:]` to delete the part until the found character.

Hope it helps.